# How do I get a 2D RayCast to completely ignore colliders with a certain tag Unity 2D

Tags: unity-game-engine, raycasting

The raycast will shoot out of the gun and hit the gun itself. If it doesn't hit itself, it hits the player holding the gun. The player is a ragdoll and often flops in front of the gun. I want it to shoot out and ignore itself and the player and only detect the scenery.
I am also confused as how to use Debug.DrawRay(Position, direction, color); How do I add length to it? Does debug.drawray not have a length option?
I've been struggling with this for a couple days now (I am a beginner) any help is greatly appreciated, thank you so much!

```
         if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.S))
         {
             if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.D))
             {
                //run shoot function

                 StartCoroutine(Shoot());

             }
         }
     }
     IEnumerator Shoot()
     {

         //direction = destination - source
         Vector2 direction = (ShootHere.transform.position - transform.position);
         RaycastHit2D hitInfo = Physics2D.Raycast(transform.position, direction, 40);
         Debug.DrawRay(transform.position, direction, Color.red);
       //This is me trying to get the raycast to not hit the player hitbox, this does not do that, it just causes 
       //the raycast to end the detection when it hits the object and instead procead to draw a line (The else statement)
       //How do I get my raycast to ignore the tagged objects and to detect the next object past itself and the player?
         if (hitInfo && hitInfo.collider.tag != "Player1" && hitInfo.collider.name != gameObject.name)
         {
             Debug.Log("RayCast hit a hitbox, the name is" + hitInfo.collider.name);
             lineRenderer.positionCount = 2;
             lineRenderer.SetPosition(0, transform.position);
             lineRenderer.SetPosition(1, hitInfo.point);
         }
         else
         {
             lineRenderer.positionCount = 2;
             lineRenderer.SetPosition(0, transform.position);
             lineRenderer.SetPosition(1, ShootHere.position + ShootHere.right * 100);
         }
         lineRenderer.enabled = true;
         yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.02f);
         lineRenderer.enabled = false;
     }
 }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I would use [Physics2D.RaycastAll](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics2D.RaycastAll.html) instead and loop through all Raycasthits.

[Debug.DrawRay(start, dir)](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Debug.DrawRay.html) draws a line from `start` to `start + dir` in world coordinates.